# Where to handle StaleObjectStateException in asp.net mvc application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, staleobjectstate

I'm using Session per Request pattern. Transactions are managed automatically.

How can I easily handle StaleObjectStateException and show some specific view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to override OnException in your controller and if a StateObjectStateException occurs, you could set the Result on the ExceptionContext to your error view result.

```
public override void OnException( ExceptionContext context )
{
    if (context.Exception is StateObjectStateException)
    {
        context.Result = View("error");
        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good solution but... I need to Rollback transaction because setting ExceptionHandled to true clears exception bubbling.

PS
I review my questions and answers. Unfortunately nobody give me answer which will be satisfactory. Probably yours will be first :)